# The website program is installed under the local wampserver, but the access path still jumps to the domain name

Tags: wamp

I downloaded the magento 2 website program and database for local debugging of the local computer wampserver. I have installed the website program and database, but I now enter the path: localhost/supwatch/

The website can be opened, but jumping to the domain name of my website is not a local path! How to solve it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 then setup:upgrade cache:flush

Comment: setup:upgrade cache:flush how to se it ? thanks!  my path:  D:\wamp64\www\supwatch

Comment: Go to your root and run these commands

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento cache:flush then see the result and hope it helps you

Comment: i open win 10 Command prompt （via:  CMD）,then write: php bin/magento setup:upgrade  it couldn't work

Comment: go to your magento folder in your case should be htdocs/yourmagentoroot then run the above commands

Comment: i have try is! but it remind "not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91338/discussion-between-prathap-gunasekaran-and-nextion).

Comment: I think I did not configure environment variables under wampserver, which made it impossible to use php. How to set environment variables? Is there a corresponding tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

1.Open core_config_data table

2.change values of secure and unsecure base urls with 127.0.0.1  .

[image]

Then clean cache. Run setup upgrade and static deployement commands

Comment: it couldn't set it!